# My MAC address does not match the MAC value within remotely-generated Version 1 UUID

Tags: uuid, mac-address

When I create a version 1 UUID on this [website](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/version1), for all version 1 generations, last 48 bits are the same. I did some research and saw that it is the MAC address of the machine/host that UUID being created. However, I don't know which MAC address of my PC is this one. I checked the MAC addresses seen by `ipconfig -all` on Windows, but none of them were same with the value shown in the UUIDs.

I nmost probably misinterpret something, would be glad if anyone makes it clear for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I seriously doubt that websites have access to your MAC address by any mechanism (short of you entering it into a form manually), so it wouldn't be able to take that into consideration when generating a UUID on that site. If I pull up the developer tools and watch the network traffic when loading and submitting the form, I don't see a MAC ever transmitted to the website.

I'm going to guess that it's "emulating" a MAC address by using other information, like your public IP address combined with something else like your user-agent (both of which it does have access to).

It wouldn't even be *that* hard to do. Concatenate the IP + User Agent + Whatever else into a long string, hash the string, turn it into binary, then truncate it to 48-bits. That should be largely unique; even among users sharing the same public IP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is interesting you got different least significant 48 bits of UUIDs on the same mobile phone. Because I tried from my pc(wifi), my phone(wifi), and my phone(cellular data) and all of them resulted in same lower 48 bits.

Comment: Using another browser on mobile phone with different browser, again the same lower 48 bits. I could not understand how at least wifi and cellular data does not make any difference

Comment: @muyustan Actually, I was wrong. I had accidentally generated a v4 UUID when I visited it on my phone. I do in fact, as you said, get the same result on my phone as I did on my laptop. That alone shows that it can't be using your MAC address though. I don't know what precise fingerprinting method they're using, but it isn't your MAC.

Comment: Correct Answer. A [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) stays within your local subnet, behind a router. Past that router only your IP is trafficked. The [*UUID Generator*](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/version1) site is applying its own MAC address when generating a [Version 1 UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)). And most likely that web app is inventing a fictional MAC address, as there are security implications to sharing your true MAC address.

Comment: @BasilBourque Ya, it seemed ridiculous that the browser would allow the MAC to be shared (or that the OS would even share it with the browser in the first place). Was worth a check though just to be sure. I am curious though what exactly they are basing it on. I tried from different public IPs, on different computers, and vastly different browsers, and I get the same result each time regardless. Unless it's the same for everyone (although that seems unlikely). Do you get it ending in 30002 out of curiosity?

Comment: I guess too that "the MAC address of **the computer on which it was generated**" could be taken literally too, so you'll get the same ending unless you're served from a different server/interface than someone else.